# How tor browser gets obfs4proxy?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, obfsproxy

When you start tor you can choose connection type using obfs4 proxy. How Tor browser gets the list of obfs4proxy ? It download it using clearnet ?

Answer (score 0):

Tor Browser comes with a bunch of `obfs4` bridges, which is put into Tor Launcher at build time. Tor Browser also has a mechanism called [Moat](https://gitweb.torproject.org/bridgedb.git/tree/README.rst#n411), which, if possible, fetches fresh bridges from BridgeDB. All those can be configured in [prefs.js](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-launcher.git/tree/src/defaults/preferences/prefs.js).